# Closing accordion

Tags: javascript, wordpress, accordion

I made a site using a wordpress template that included an accordion module within the live composer. I am trying to fix the accordion so it will open AND close the sections on click.

Below is a link to the accordion.

http://www.desertpeak.biz/customer-service-3/

Comment: Your link is broken, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find in your Javascript where you are triggering your slideDown() at, but I would suggest using [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) on your click statement.  This jQuery function will slide the element down/show if it is closed, and slide the element up/hide if it is shown.

Comment: Would it get added here? $( document ).ready( function () {

        // Expand/Collapse on click
        $( '.accordion-container' ).on( 'click keydown', '.accordion-section-title', function( e ) {
            if ( e.type === 'keydown' && 13 !== e.which ) // "return" key
                    return;
            e.preventDefault(); // Keep this AFTER the key filter above

            accordionSwitch( $( this ) );
        });

        // Re-initialize accordion when screen options are toggled
        $( '.hide-postbox-tog' ).click( function () {
            accordionInit();
        });

    });

Comment: /* Module output stars here */ 

        $accordion_nav = explode( '(dslc_sep)', trim( $options['accordion_nav'] ) );

        if ( empty( $options['accordion_content'] ) )
            $accordion_contents = false;
        else
            $accordion_contents = explode( '(dslc_sep)', trim( $options['accordion_content'] ) );

        $count = 0;

    ?>